# How to allow for resizing of columns and subscribe to PreviewMouseDown?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF-Datagrid with a Number of columns and I use the PreviewMouseDown Event to do some custom handling, like setting the background colour of the Columns. That works just fine.
My trouble comes from the fact that the PreviewMouseDown is also fired when somebody tries to resize the Columns. The "<->" Cursor is shown, but the event is send to PreviewMouseDown and I have found no way to distinguish between a normal click and resizing.

Note: I am using Caliburn Micros Events. They should just forward specific events to methods, so there is probably no interference.
XAML:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="excelDataTable_ExcelData"  IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewMouseDown] = [Action HeaderSelected($EventArgs)]">

</DataGrid>
```

C# code:

```
 public void HeaderSelected(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question only, you can check for the 'Cursors' type in Preview event, if its not what you want say e.handled = true.

Comment: THank you very much. That actually works. Unfortunately, it got reset when I have to change the contents of the DataGrid. Which happens quite often :(

Comment: I down voted your one sentence answer because it only has one sentence in it and falls *far* below the usual standard for answers on this website.